# How can I use both Anaconda and nevertheless import packages into my standalone python version?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

I'm relatively new to python and have installed a standalone version of python3.8.6 on my Mac computer. More recently I installed also Anaconda, which applies other python 3.8 versions in its virtual environments. However if I try to install a package as e.g. "requests" with "python3 -m pip install requests" in my python 3.8.6 version I get the message: "Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.24.0)....."(the messages is much longer) and my standalone python 3.8.6 scripts cannot find that module if I import it, saying: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'". So Anaconda seems to block the installation of packages in my standalone python 3.8.6 version.
How can I use both Anaconda (for special purposes and courses) and nevertheless import packages into my standalone python 3.8.6 version?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. It could perhaps interesting for other newbies! I just had forgotten to deactivate conda (conda deactivate). It remained in a active environment, called "base". After I deactivated conda, I could use pip for my standalone python.